# How to set cross half background for cell ? Like below url

Tags: javascript, css

See this image url i'm expecting like below url image
http://hall4u.com/images/first-half-booked.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might by one of the solution as per my assumption

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #111;
    position:relative;
}
.container:before {
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.container:after {
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 100px solid green;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/ku0gozhq/)